# How to copy content between forms

Tags: jquery

I have two forms:

```
<form method="post"> 
   Titulo <input type = "text" name="titulo_principal" value="">
   <!-- other filds -->
</form>
```

And

```
<form method="post" id="ajax_form"> 
  Titulo <input type = "text" name="titulo" value="">
  <!-- other filds -->
</form>
```

How do I get Title field of the first form also appears in the title field of the second form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the title of your first form. It doesn't have an ID, so you can use the `form:first` selector. Then, select the input element of the second form that you want to change, and change the value with `.val`

Like this,

```
var title = $('form:first').children('[name="titulo_principal"]').val();
$('#ajax_form').children('[name="titulo"]').val(title);
```

EDIT:
If you want the second title to be updated when the first one is changed, you can do this

```
$('form:first').children('[name="titulo_principal"]').on('input', function() {
    var title = $(this).val();
    $('#ajax_form').children('[name="titulo"]').val(title);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, but including the above code in the <script> tag in the head and entering the id the first form did not work

Comment: It works, check out this [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/L79o2c6q/).  Are you properly including jQuery? Is the code inside of [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)?

Comment: Oh yes now I have seen that it works, but in fact need to be using the function .change

Comment: What do you mean? When the first form's title changes you want the second form's title to change as well?

Comment: Exactly, typing in the first form the second form field in the title be changed

Comment: Use `.on('input'...` not `.change('input'...`

Comment: Yes I try two options but no alteration

Comment: I´m using <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/1.7.1_jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: The jquery ajax  (id="ajax_form") is working on the second form normally. In browser's console not display errors. I do not know what happens

Comment: It works when put in footer. Thank you so much  @Andrew Brooke

Comment: It should work anywhere if you wrap it in `$( document ).ready()`, but I'm glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Now finally understand when to use `$ (document) .ready ()`. Hyper thank you